# How to make progress dialog in fragment tab in Android?

Tags: android

I have MainActivity which added two fragment tab namely "tab1 and "tab2.tab 1 sends some request to server during this process I Want to show a progress dialog but when I do this through a error message "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application" and also have some implementation of Broadcast receiver in tab 1 fragment which also through error "unable to register receiver"

Progress dialog code:

```
public class DialogUtils {

    public static ProgressDialog showProgressDialog(Context context, String message) {
        ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        m_Dialog.setMessage(message);
        m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        m_Dialog.show();
        return m_Dialog;

    }

}
```

Mainactivity code:

```
m_TabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);// finding Id of tablayout
    m_ViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);//finding Id of ViewPager
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Deals"));// add deal listin tab
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Stories"));
    m_TabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);// setting Gravity of Tab


    CDealMainListingPager m_oDealMainScreenPager = new CDealMainListingPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), m_TabLayout.getTabCount());
    m_ViewPager.setAdapter(m_oDealMainScreenPager);// adiing adapter to ViewPager
    m_ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(m_TabLayout));// performing action of page changing
    m_TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

and tab1 fragment tab code:

```
public static final String TAG = CDealAppListing.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int m_TRANSACTION_SUCCESSFUL = 0;
public static String m_szMobileNumber;//declaring String mobile number variable
public static String m_szEncryptedPassword;//declaring string password  variable
public static String sz_RecordCount;// //declaring String record count variable variable
public static String sz_LastCount;//declaring String lastcount  variable
private static ListView m_ListView;// declaring Listview variable..
private static CDealAppListingAdapter m_oAdapter;// declaring DealListingAdapter..
public CDealAppDatastorage item;// declaring DealAppdataStorage
public View mFooter;
public AppCompatButton m_BtnRetry;
/*This Broadcast receiver will listen network state accordingly
which enable or disable create an account button*/
private final BroadcastReceiver m_oInternetChecker = new BroadcastReceiver() {// creating broadcast to receive otp sent by server from Inbox...
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {// on receive method to read OTP sent by server
        changeButtonState();// check whether edit text is empty or not

    }
};
RequestQueue requestQueue;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
private ArrayList<CDealAppDatastorage> s_oDataset;// declaring Arraylist variable
private int[] m_n_FormImage;//declaring integer array varaible
private View m_Main;//declaring View variable
private int m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// intiallly record count is 5.
private int m_n_DeafalutLastCount = 0;//initally lastcount is 0.
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefresh;
private ProgressDialog m_Dialog;
private boolean bBottomOfView;
private LinearLayout m_NoInternetWarning;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_listing, container, false);//intialize mainLayout
    Log.i(TAG, "OnCreateView.........");
    init();
    return m_Main;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume.........");
    /*Registered Broadcast receiver*/
    IntentFilter m_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();// creating object of Intentfilter class user for defining permission
    m_intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");// action to check Internet connection
    getActivity().registerReceiver(m_oInternetChecker, m_intentFilter);// register receiver....

    getDetails();

}


public void changeButtonState() {
    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        m_BtnRetry.setEnabled(true);
        m_BtnRetry.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 80, 147));// set background color on eabled
    } else {
        m_BtnRetry.setEnabled(false);
        m_BtnRetry.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button
    }
}

private void getDetails() {// get details of user from shared preference...
    CLoginSessionManagement m_oSessionManagement = new CLoginSessionManagement(getActivity());// crating object of Login Session
    HashMap<String, String> user = m_oSessionManagement.getLoginDetails();// get String from Login Session
    m_szMobileNumber = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_MOBILE).trim();// getting password from saved preferences..........
    m_szEncryptedPassword = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_PASSWORD).trim();// getting mobile num from shared preferences...

    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// increment of record count
    m_n_DeafalutLastCount = 0;
    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// increment of last count...

    s_oDataset = new ArrayList<>();// making object of Arraylist


    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        postDealListingDatatoServer();// here sending request in onCreate
    } else {
        mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        m_BtnRetry.setEnabled(false);
        m_BtnRetry.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button

    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy...............");
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(m_oInternetChecker);// unregistaer broadcast receiver.
}

private void init() {// initialize controls

    m_NoInternetWarning = (LinearLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.no_internet_warning);
    m_BtnRetry = (AppCompatButton) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.btn_retry);
    m_BtnRetry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            retryRequest(v);
        }
    });
    m_ListView = (ListView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.dealList);// findind Id of Listview
    m_ListView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    m_ListView.setOnScrollListener(this);
    /*Swipe to refresh code*/
    mSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    mSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh_progress_1);

    mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            /*Here check net connection avialable or not */
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// increment of record count
                        m_n_DeafalutLastCount = 0;
                        sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// increment of last count...
                        swipeData();
                    }
                }, 3500);

            } else {
                m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (mSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {

                    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    m_n_FormImage = new int[]{// defining Images in Integer array
            R.drawable.amazon,
            R.drawable.whatsapp,
            R.drawable.zorpia,
            R.drawable.path,
            R.drawable.app_me,
            R.drawable.evernote,
            R.drawable.app_me};
}

public void retryRequest(View v) {
    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        m_BtnRetry.setEnabled(true);
        m_BtnRetry.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 80, 147));// set background color on eabled
        sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// increment of record count
        m_n_DeafalutLastCount = 0;
        sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// increment of last count...

        postDealListingDatatoServer();
    } else {
        m_BtnRetry.setEnabled(false);
        m_BtnRetry.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button
    }

}
    /*This is new changes in code ....using Volley instead of AsynkTask*/

/*This method send request to server for deallisting*/
// this method send request to server for deal list....
public void postDealListingDatatoServer() {
    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        System.out.println("Record Count:-" + sz_RecordCount);
        System.out.println("LastCount:-" + sz_LastCount);
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

        Log.i(TAG, "Server Request:-" + json);
        m_Dialog = DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Loading...");
        final String m_DealListingURL = "http://202.131.144.132:8080/json/metallica/getDealListInJSON";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);
                m_Dialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("resultcode"));
                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_TRANSACTION_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response
                        s_oDataset.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                            item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                            item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                            item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
                            item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
                            item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
                            s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

                        }


                        if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {// condition if data in arraylist is not empty
                            m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                            m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                            m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        } else {
                            m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);// else Load buttonvisibility set to Gone
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Technical Failure")) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server error:-" + error);
                m_Dialog.dismiss();
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                    mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Change DialogUtils class:

```
public static ProgressDialog showProgressDialog(Activity activity, String message) {
    ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    m_Dialog.setMessage(message);
    m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
    m_Dialog.show();
    return m_Dialog;

}
```

Step2: Change the postDealListingDatatoServer() method.

```
m_Dialog = DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Loading...");
```

Step3: About broadcast receiver. Please register at the onResume() method and unregister at the onPause() method.

Comment: this is showing me error :- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41fdc330 V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,144} not attached to window manager

Comment: JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);
     if (m_Dialog != null && m_Dialog.isShowing()) {
      m_Dialog.dismiss();
     }

Comment: in mDialog.dismiss

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ProgressDialog showProgressDialog(Context context, String message) {
    ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    m_Dialog.setMessage(message);
    m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
    if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
         m_Dialog.show();
    }

    return m_Dialog;
}
```

To dismiss dialog:

```
if ((m_Dialog!= null) && m_Dialog.isShowing())
    m_Dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if fragment is visible or not.

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (this.isVisible()) {
            // If we are becoming invisible, then...

            if (!isVisibleToUser) {

                }

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```